# Print letters not in string

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying to see if a word or sentence has each letter of the alphabet and I can't get it to print all the letters that isn't in the sentence/word.

```
alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t'
,'u','v','w','x','y','z']
x = raw_input('')
counter  = 0
counter2 = 0
for i in range(len(x))
    counter += 1
    for o in range(26):
        counter2 += 1
        if alpha[counter2] not in x[counter]:
```

and I'm stuck there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `set difference`:

```
import string
x=raw_input()
not_found=set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set("".join(x.split()))
print (list(not_found))
```

**output:**

```
>>> 
the quick brown fox
['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'm', 'l', 'p', 's', 'v', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: It isn't actually necessary to remove the whitespace with "".join(x.split()) since set difference doesn't require a strict subset.

Answer (score 4):

```
alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t'
,'u','v','w','x','y','z'}
input_chars = set(raw_input())
print alphabet - input_chars
```

All we do is set difference between the set of alphabet characters and the set of characters in our input. Note that the difference operation can take as a second operand any iterable, so we don't even really have to turn our input into a set if we don't want to, although this will speed up the difference a small amount. Furthermore, there is a built-in string which gives us the ascii letters so we could do it like this:

```
import string
print set(string.ascii_lowercase) - raw_input()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already iterating over both strings, there is no need to use `counter` and `counter2`.

You were almost there. Python makes list operations simple, so there's no need to iterate over the lists element-by-element using indices:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
sentence = raw_input('Enter a sentence: ').lower()  # Because 'a' != 'A'

letters = []

for letter in sentence:
    if letter in alphabet and letter not in letters:
        letters.append(letter)

print(letters)
```

Comment: This one is good but it prints whats in there not what isn't in there.

Comment: I'm sure you can modify the code. If you can't do this yourself with basic Python lists and loops, there's no use in learning about set operations.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier:

```
 import string
 x = raw_input()
 print [c for c in string.ascii_lowercase if c not in x]
```